# I am using #pragma directives startup and exit but output is unexpected

Tags: c

In reference to the below mentioned code ,#pragma startup f1 will call f1() before main() and #pragma exit f2 will call f2() when main() ends. But when I am executing the program, the output is not as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f1();
void f2();
#pragma startup f1
#pragma exit f2
int main()
{
    printf("Inside main\n");
    return 0;
}
void f1()
{
    printf("Inside f1\n");
}
void f2()
{
    printf("Inside f2\n");
}
```

Output :

Inside main

Expected Output :

Inside f1

Inside main

Inside f2

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: GNU GCC. Do pragmas vary from one build tool to another ?

Comment: @ritvik: unless the directive starts `#pragma STDC`, the action is implementation-defined (standard section 6.1.6). So, yes, they vary.

Comment: gcc doesn't support pragma startup nor pragma exit. Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` or `-Wunknown-pragmas`

Comment: @KamilCuk However, `gcc` *does* have `__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((destructor))`.

Comment: regarding the prototypes: `void f1();` and `void f2();`  To force the compiler to produce code that will take NO parameters to those functions, insert a `void` between the parens I.E. `void f1( void );` and `void f2( void );`

Comment: @EOF 
void __attribute__((constructor)) f1();  
void __attribute__((destructor)) f2(); works.